# how to display the data from DB in textarea

Tags: php, forms, get, textarea

In the following code, I can display the values from the DB in text boxes but how would I display them in the textarea?

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
  <div>
     <p>
     <strong>ID:</strong>    
     <?php echo $id; ?>
     </p>
     <strong>userid: </strong>    
     <input type="text" name="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" /><br/>
     <strong>name: </strong>     
     <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><br/>
     <strong>phoneno: </strong>      
     <input type="text" name="phoneno" value="<?php echo $phoneno; ?>" /><br/>
     <strong>emailid: </strong> 
     <input type="text" name="emailid" value="<?php echo $emailid; ?>" /><br/>
     <strong>description: </strong>    
     <textarea name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" rows="5" cols="40">    </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle to find whats wrong in that add full code OR add full full code

Comment: If you are a new developer, read docs before asking questions here.http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in the tags like this:

```
<textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="40"><?= $description; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the value in text area use this

```
<textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<textarea name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea name="description"  rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="description"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
```